# HorizontalPodAutoscaler scaling based on custom metrics - node-pool level metric

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am currently trying to set up a GKE cluster and to configure an `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` based on a custom metric (GPU consumption).
I have two node-pools and I want to horizontally scale them based on the average GPU consumption of **each** `node_pool`. I have configured two identical HPA like this:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: ner
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: ner
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
    - type: External
      external:
        metric:
          name: kubernetes.io|container|accelerator|duty_cycle
        target:
          type: AverageValue
          averageValue: 60
```

where I only replace the `scaleTargetRef` but it turns out that this metric seems to be aggregated at a cluster level. I have double checked that the `scaleTargetRef` are properly defined.

Is there a way to filter the metrics by `container_name` or `node_pool`? Any other suggestion would be awesome !

Answer (score 1):

So I think you are looking for metrics for your k8 cluster especially by `container_name` or `node_pool`.

You have five types of metrics you can use in an HPA object(autoscaling/v2beta2)

```
k explain HorizontalPodAutoscaler.spec.metrics.type  --api-version=autoscaling/v2beta2
```

*Edit update*

- [ContainerResource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)
- External # Use this if [the metrics not related to Kubernetes objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-metrics-not-related-to-kubernetes-objects).
- Object
- Pods
- Resource

---

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: ner
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: ner
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
    - type: ContainerResource
      containerResource:
        name: gpu
        container: your-application-container
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 60
```

---

*Edit Update*

For GKP [Autoscaling Deployments with Cloud Monitoring metrics](http://Cluster:%20https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/autoscaling-metrics#custom-metric_4)

Comment: @Jules - the reason for the error is `Kubernetes version` If you see my answer I explicitly specified `api-version`. I'm using `v1.20.2`. If I'm no wrong you have to update the kubect version.

Comment: @Jules Follow https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/autoscaling-metrics#custom-metric_4 for custum metrics